# Mathematica installation fails on mac after download manager completes downloading

Tags: installation

I have purchased a  Mathematica Student license. To download it there are the steps

1. Download the download manager.
2. Install it.
3. Run it to get it to download the actual Mathematica installer .dmg file.
4. Run the installer to install Mathematica.

When I tried to carry out the following steps there was no response whatsoever after step 3. It was as if I never had any thoing todo with mathematica in the first place.the download manager. It just said that failed to open some file "M-OSX-L-12.0.0-6206964.dmg". There were two buttons "Browse" and "Launch". On succesive tries trying anyone of them was useless. Nothing would happen. I have read the following links 
[1](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/917946), [2](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1211541)

Comment: Did you contact WRI?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @MichaelE2 I didn't since the workaround sort of fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems to one workaround by this article on [wolfram website](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/25578). One can download the direct download .dmg file. It is a little slow , but it completes the job.